# Selectively Removing Characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an XLS dataset (33K records).  This set contains substrings I would like to replace/remove.

Targets include

Dimensional Prefix, like:  OD, ID, L, W, THK - The position of these prefix strings is not rigidly consistent in the data

Examples:

```
Before:
OD4.5MMXL38MM
L140MM
ID6MM
L14-18MMXW14-21MMXTHK24-26MM

After:
4.5MMX38MM
140MM
6MM
14-18MMX14-21MMX24-26MM
```

The substrings noted above appear within longer strings:

```
SCREW BONE OD2.7MMXL22MM SELF TAPPING LOCKING T8 STARDRIVE RECESS SS NON STERILE
```

Is there any way to use `SUBSTITUTE()` or `REPLACE()` to make these kinds of adjustments?  Note:  I can parse/isolate the dimension strings listed above - to narrow the focus - I just cannot remove those prefix strings effectively.

Thanks!

Comment: With the dimension string in `A1` you can clean the text with nested `SUBSTITUTE` formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"L",""),"OD",""),"ID",""),"W",""),"THK","")` but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!

This is a one-time task

Comment: Thnks for nested subst statement - perfectly workable, actually.  This will work just fine on the dimension strings I have parsed into XLS columns.  Then - concat & reassemble the long strings.

Comment: @user3964075: you should add that as a proposed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dimension string in A1 you can clean the text with nested SUBSTITUTE formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"L",""),"OD",""),"ID‌​",""),"W",""),"THK","")
```